# Описание причины отклонения "скопированное содержимое" на английском языке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, отклонённые-правки

В описании причины отклонения **скопированное содержимое** текст на английском языке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В указанном сообщении изменилась ссылка на блог, та часть, которая "useful to this community *specifically*". Из-за этого слетел перевод. Взял перевод из прежней версии текста, но с новой ссылкой. [Получилось так](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/113612619?key=5c0ce5a7ba640a0ff08faebbd7e97d67):

> Внесённая правка в значительной степени повторяет внешний источник. Обобщённые описания, такие как энциклопедические статьи и рекламные тексты, не могут быть полезны практически; постарайтесь создать что-то [полезное *специально* для данного сообщества](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) и обязательно укажите ссылку на автора источника. Подробнее — как делать ссылки на материал, написанный другими авторами.

Будет доступно на сайте после утверждения базы transifex и сборки сайта.

Comment: Ах вот оно что...ну как появится метка "статус-завершено", отмечу верным )

Comment: @DenisBubnov милости просим :)